# Rxjava - when chaining observables how to get back other type of stream(return value) instead of current?

Tags: java, rx-java

**I have a retrofit2 observable call i execute and right after it completes it chains to another observable to store the results into a db.It looks simply like this:**

```
    protected Observable<List<Long>> buildUseCaseObservable() {
         return mDataRepo.fetchCountries().flatMap(new Function<List<CountryModel>, ObservableSource<List<Long>>>() {
             @Override
             public ObservableSource<List<Long>> apply(@NonNull List<CountryModel> countryModels) throws Exception {
                 return mDataRepo.storeCountries(countryModels);
             }
         });
     }
```

Now my issue is i want the subscriber to get back the results of the first observable. So id like the 
         subscriber to get back `<List<CountryModel>>` instead of what its getting back now of `<List<Long>>`. Is there anyway to do this ?  Not sure if concat can help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, yes, you can use `flatMap()` variant with `resultSelector`, their you can select or combine from both input and output of `flatMap()` and in your case simply returns the fetched countries instead of ids:

```
protected Observable<List<CountryModel>> buildUseCaseObservable() {
    Repo mDataRepo = new Repo();
    return mDataRepo.fetchCountries()
            .flatMap(new Function<List<CountryModel>, ObservableSource<List<Long>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<Long>> apply(
                        @android.support.annotation.NonNull List<CountryModel> countryModels) throws Exception {
                    return mDataRepo.storeCountries(countryModels);
                }
            }, new BiFunction<List<CountryModel>, List<Long>, List<CountryModel>>() {
                @Override
                public List<CountryModel> apply(List<CountryModel> countryModels,
                                                List<Long> longs) throws Exception {
                    return countryModels;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Ctrl-c ctrl-v in Android studio? 

Comment: Well, you should know that some times it doesn't convert properly 

Comment: @DouglasMesquita See example here: https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/rxjava-kotlin-keep-the-original-value-in-a-flatmap-bbd6a6974a99