# RxJava get result of previous observable in chained network request

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have 2 service endpoints in my application `a` and `b` (Both are "Singles"). The request to service `b` depends on the response of `a`. After the the response of `b` I need access to both responses in my subscriber. I plan to do the call like this:

```
services.a()
    .flatMap(a -> services.b(a))
    .subscribe(b ->
        // Access a and b here
    )
```

But in this way, I only can access the result of `b` in my subscriber. How can I pass also the response of `a` to it?

My first attempt was to use something like this:

```
// Note: Code will not compile... Just to show the concept
services.a()
    .flatMap(
        a -> Observable.combineLatest(
                Observable.just(a)
                services.b(a).toObservable()
                Bifunction((a, b) -> {return Pair<ResponseA, ResponseB>(a, b)}))
    )
    .toSingle()
    .subscribe(pair -> {
        ResponseA a = pair.first();
        ResponseB b = pair.second();
    })
```

But as the use case gets a bit more complex, the code will evolve to an ugly monster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variant of `flatMap()` with `resultSelector`, `resultSelector` method will gather both input (a) and output (result of Observable b) of the `flatMap` and you can combine them together to whatever you need. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623224/3903847).

Comment: There is no such method for `Single`, see here for a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695307/1000551