# RxJava 2, what happen the resultSelector argument of flatmap?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

In RxJava1 `flatmap` had a overloaded method that allowed you to retain source values and pass it down the stream.

I've gained this knowledge from the following blog post

https://medium.com/rxjava-tidbits/rxjava-tidbits-1-use-flatmap-and-retain-original-source-value-4ec6a2de52d4

However, moving to RxJava2, I cannot seem to find it. I checked the changes from Rx1 and Rx2 and it is not listed.
I would like to know if it exists still but I am perhaps not looking in the right place.

I am using a `Single` by the way.

Comment: I don't think `Single` ever had that. `Observable` and [`Flowable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) still do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `Single` ever supported this operator and the `Observable`/`Flowable` operators are still there. You can accomplish this behavior by mapping the result of the inner source:

```
source.flatMap(originalValue -> 
    createInnerSource(originalValue)
    .map(innerValue -> process(originalValue, innerValue))
)
```

The lambda of the `map` will capture the `originalValue` for you.

Comment: Ah so I create a wrapper model and map each result to it and keep passing it down the chain? So essentially the function type of each flatmap will be my wrapper model